# Arithmetic operation on mixed data type in C++

Tags: c++

I want to understand how arithmetic operation happen on different data type,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

void newprintf(int, int, long, char *);

int main()
{
    int i = 22;
    newprintf(14, 30, (long) i, "9,999");
    getch();
    return 0;   
}

void newprintf(int r, int c, long val, char *format)
{
    char *p, str[20];
    int len, i, j, lstr;

    len = strlen(format);
    _itoa(val, str, 10);
    lstr = strlen(str);
    p = str;
    c += len;
    p = str + lstr -1;
    format = format + len - 1;
    cout << "The value in p : " << p << endl;
    cout << "The format is : " << format << endl;
}
```

Basically this program doesn't have a specific functionality, i just wanted to understand how the value of 'p' and 'format' are calculated, This program is compiled on Visual Studio.
Can anyone explain me how the value are calculated in **detail** ?
On running i get,
p = 2 and format = 9

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char *p` is a pointer to a char in memory. `char str[20]` is an array large enough to hold 20 characters. `str[0]` is a pointer to the first element in the array `str`. The line `p = str` is setting the character pointer `p` to point to the beginning of the array `str`.

`strlen` returns the number of characters in a string, so `lstr = strlen(str)` is setting `lstr` to the number of characters in the `str` array.

When adding or subtracting pointers, you are shifting the pointer according to the type. See the below example.

```
char *p, str[20];
p = str; //p now points to the beginning of str (a.k.a str[0])

p++; // We shifted p over by one character
     //  now (*p) == str[1]

p += 3; // We shifted p over 3 more characters
       //   now (*p) == str[1+3]
```

Back to your example, `p = str + lstr - 1` is setting p to point to the base of `str` plus the number of characters in `str` (which is 20) minus 1. The minus one is important because if we were to do `str + lstr` and access `str[20]` we would be going out of bounds.

Essentially `p` is being set such that it points to the last character in the `str` array.

Comment: Thank you, At last i got the concept. :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have so-called operators. You can also write your own operators. There is many resources on net where you can check in detail how some operator works in detail. This probably will help you and answer that  all things: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: Thanks for the informantion